# How do I send a value from a gridview control button field to another page?

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

```
protected void GridView3_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Drill")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView3.Rows[index];
        TableCell sitenamecell = selectedRow.Cells[1];
        string Site = sitenamecell.Text;
        Session["Location"] = Site;
        lblSession.Text = Session["Location"].ToString();
        Response.Redirect("DisplayForm.aspx");
```

Comment: why you dont just store it in the session as you do it right now? in the session it stays on another page too...

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as a GET variable:

```
GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView3.Rows[index];
TableCell sitenamecell = selectedRow.Cells[1];
string Site = sitenamecell.Text;
Session["Location"] = Site;
lblSession.Text = Session["Location"].ToString();
Response.Redirect("DisplayForm.aspx?site=" + Site);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your other page is the page you are redirecting to?

If so just add whatever you want to the query string:

```
Response.Redirect("DisplayForm.aspx?yourParamNameHere=" + yourParamNameValue);
```

You can use the session but then you have to worry about the back button, forward buttons and multiple tabs (instances) messing up what is stored in the session.  The safest method is to just make it part of the query string that your receiving page looks for.